# Plot not showing the exact values of my series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot my pandas Series with its values but having wrong values on my x-axis. I have done the same thing more than 3 times on the same workbook. What am doing wrong here?

```
S1=rog1.groupby('Date')['availabi'].mean()
S1.index
# output
DatetimeIndex(['2018-05-10', '2018-06-10', '2018-07-10'], 
dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

But when I decide to plot the lot.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.plot(S1.index, S1)
```

The below is what I get

[image]

The y-axis values are fine. I dunno where the plotted values are coming from. I only have 3 lines in this Series

Comment: I am unable to reproduce make sure that `S1` is not another variable called somewhere else in the notebook. define and call it in the same cell

Comment: I don't know exactly what is wrong, but I think that if you add `plt.xticks(S1.index, S1.index.date)` before `plt.plot(...`, you should get what you are looking for

Comment: @Chris S1 is series obtained after the groupby. Plotting S1, is plotting just the values S1 not the index itself. That is why I am also plotting the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that matplotlib auto-detects the number and spacing of x-ticks to populate the x-axis without overlapping labels, and also without leaving too much white space.

The simplest workaround I can think of:
1. Create figure and axis handles
2. Plot your data in the axis
3. Manually set the xtick positions and labels

Code to replace your two lines of plotting:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
S1.plot(ax=ax)
ax.set_xticks(S1.index);
ax.set_xticklabels(S1.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'));
```

Comment: @Herc01, I'm not familiar enough with matplotlib's internal workings to be sure, but the default behaviour is to automatically pick a sensible number of x-ticks for the input data. Your DataFrame only had 3 dates in the index, and your figure size was large enough to prompt matplotlib to auto-populate x-ticks instead of using only your three.